OAuth2AuthorizationException:[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized
I am using Spring Boot 3.3.0 version. I am using webclient for a POST call but getting an error:
OAuth2AuthorizationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized

This is the configuration for WebClient:
protected ABCResponse (ABCRequestBody requestBody) {
       return myprovider.post()
                      .uri(SearchUrl)
                      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                      .bodyValue(requestBody)
                      .retrieve()
                      .bodyToMono(ABCResponse.class)
                      .block();
}

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Configuration
public class MyClientRequestConfig {

    @Bean
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository getRegistration(
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myprovider.token-uri}") String token_uri,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myprovider.client-id}") String client_id,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myprovider.client-secret}") String client_secret
    ) {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("myprovider")
                .tokenUri(token_uri)
                .clientId(client_id)
                .clientSecret(client_secret)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .build();
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }

    @Bean(name = "myprovider")
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations);
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, clientService);
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("myprovider");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();

    }
}

application.yaml-
spring:
  mvc:
    throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
  resources:
    add-mappings: false
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          myprovider:
            client-id: ${GSK_CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${GSK_CLIENT_SECRET}
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic
        provider:
          myprovider:
            token-uri: ${GSK_TOKEN_ENDPT}

Error logs:
2024-08-11 21:49:47.396 | APP=GK114556  | thread=http-nio-15103-exec-5 | severity=ERROR | c.f.i.c.e.i.InternalRestExceptionHandler - 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR - [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.getTokenResponse(ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:96)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST https://apigateway.gsk.com/search/v1/products [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.getTokenResponse(ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:96)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.authorize(ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:85)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.authorize(DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.authorize(DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.java:176)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.lambda$authorizeClient$22(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:486)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.call(MonoSupplier.java:67)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:228)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:104)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1779)
        at com.gsk.institutional.distributions.dao.GSKServicesDAO.callProductSearch(GSKServicesDAO.java:110)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)

Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthorizationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.getResponse(DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.java:96)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.getTokenResponse(ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.authorize(ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.authorize(DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.authorize(DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.lambda$authorizeClient$22(ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.java:486)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.call(MonoSupplier.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:228)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:891)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.getResponse(DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.java:89)
    ... 16 common frames omitted

I was expecting a JSON response from auth endpoint.

What I understand from the code is that the client sets the Accept header whereas it's up to the server to define what is acceptable.
So I believe the statement .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) has no effect and the server behind SearchUrl does not accept JSON, that's why you get this error.
Check the contract of the server

I am getting error while generating token https://b2b-test.gsk.com/auth/token. Its unable to generate token before calling SearchUrl.
            .tokenUri(token_uri)


Ok sorry for the misunderstanding :)
Now it looks like the content-type of the token generation request does not match the content. However, I do not understand why the content is a Map.
Can you show the end of the stack trace, starting with the last "Caused by"? That is usually the most relevant part

@lolo101 I am getting unauthorized error now, added logs
